# Datetime form field collected with datepicker Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a datetime form field that collects the expiration date and time of an auction

```
<%= e.text_field :expiration, id: 'expiration' %>
```

`<%= e.time_select :expiration, :ignore_date => true %>`

I'm using jquery UI datepicker for the textfield to allow for dates to be entered as "2016-04-05" using a calendar popup

My controller for the auction only permits certain values from the params hash i.e.

```
params.require(:auction).permit(:expiration)
```

However in this setup I am getting the following error

```
1 error(s) on assignment of attribute [error on assignment [0, 26] to expiration (Missing Parameter - expiration(1))]
```

The time_select field populates expiration(4i) and expiration(5i) but the textfield cannot populate the date portion of the datetime field. Is there a work around to this?
I want to have the datepicker jquery popup but want to somehow collect the time as well. Maybe there's a way in Jquery to fire a method when a date is selected that will parse the date into day, month and year and respectively populate expiration(1i), (2i) & (3i) before the form gets submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use <%= f.datetime_select :expiration %>

If not you can try it like this maybe

```
jQuery ->
  $('#auction_expiration').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :expiration %>
  <%= f.text_field :expiration %>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this what I have, but how do collect the time and store it along with date in :expiration. When i use this for date and time_select for the time, I get an error when clicking submitting (shown above). When I use f.datetime_select i cant use Jquery's calendar popup, which I believe only works on textfields.

Comment: you don't need seperate attributes for date and time though, datetime can be used to store both and I believe jqueries datepicker requries your form field to be set to text_field  Have a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBKSjAbemo and this https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon